# Firefox messing my css

Tags: html, css

I have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/AvLa3/1/

This fiddle works perfectly in chrome and firefox. I am using the same code in my webpage, but, after a page refresh, firefox (in chrome everything works perfectly) moves this arrow left (so it is behind the letters). This is a link to my website: `https://scyk.pl`. I am talking about the `Zaloguj się` text that is in top right corner of the page.

I have no idea why it does that, can someone help me please?

Comment: I don't have the problem in Firefox.

Comment: @Rob: Uh? I tried it with my another pc, and I get the arrow beneath the letters. It only happens after a page refresh, if you move your cursor at the text, it repairs itself (also as I already mentioned, the bug occurs only in firefox).

Comment: You didn't say it only happens after page refresh.

Comment: Add `display: block` to `.login`

Comment: @davidpauljunior: Works! Thank you! Add a post here so I can accept it. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: block` to `.login`.  Ta da!